# What happened at the end of ARQ?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, arq

In the movie ARQ, what happened in the ending? Why does Hannah wake up? What happened? Does it mean that they won the war? They get shot in the previous scene, so how did they win the war?

Comment: Time loop starts over.

Comment: The time loop starts over but their memories were wiped again.

Answer (score 5):

Those are a few questions. Let me try them one at a time.

**ref: [ARQ Explanation](http://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2016/11/13/ARQ-2016-Netflix-Full-Plot-and-Ending-Explained)**

1. What happened in the ending, why Hannah wakes up instead of Ren?

   > Hannah wakes up. The film ends. Remember the person farthest from the
   >   ARQ gets their memory back the first? Looks like in the previous loop,
   >   due to slightly modified events, Hannah now ends up being the
   >   farthest. In the last sequence, the first to recollect his memories
   >   was Renton. This time it is Hannah. So they have changed the pattern
   >   from the previous sequence. They have also managed to record a longer
   >   message.

   The end of film a new loop and a new sequence begins. But this time Hannah wakes up first, which means she might be the first to recall her memories.
2. Does it mean that they won the war?

   No it doesn't mean that. The loop resets and a new sequence begins. That's all. They get shot in the 9th loop of the previous series but the ARQ caues a loop reset and everything begins again.

   > Would this be enough to get the ARQ successfully to the Bloc? May be,
   >   maybe not. The warning message from the previous cycle may be enough
   >   to give Hannah and Renton an upper hand in this sequence. But now
   >   given Hannah is the first to wake up, it may lead to them not checking
   >   the logs soon enough. Renton is the one who knows the ARQ has logs, so
   >   the later he regains memories from the sequence of loops, the later he
   >   will check the logs.